# Android Aplicativo fecha ao adicionar Firebase e cardview

Tags: java, android, android-gradle

Toda vez que adiciono :

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.+'
```

e

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
```

Juntos o aplicativo simplesmente não funciona. Como resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, tudo bem!?

especifique a versão completa, aqui estou usando e funcionando:

```
// CardView
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0' 

//firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
```

Uma dia: use apenas os serviços necessários do firebase para o funcionamento do seu app, como fiz acima (especifique o que quer, como auth, database, storage, etc), assim não incluirá todas bibliotecas do firebase sem necessidade.

Comment: Acabei modificando o projeto e removendo o cardview, porém agora as mensagens do Firebase não chegam.

Comment: nao havia a necessidade, os cards mais cedo ou mais tarde vc irá precisar deles

Comment: Acho que não. Você poderia me ajudar em outra questão? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/355493/fcm-firebase-messaging-service-com-o-app-inativo

Comment: posso sim, vou la conferir